# Tkinter 'if' statement returning incorrect text

Tags: python, tkinter

When I try a number it gives me `invalid` but I only want it to say `invalid` if it's a negative or not a number:

```
from Tkinter import *
import tkMessageBox

class MyApp(object):
def __init__(self):
    self.root = Tk()
    self.root.wm_title("Question 7")
    self.label = Label(self.root, text="Enter weight in pounds",
                       font=('Calibri', 50))
    self.label.pack(padx=20,pady=10)
    self.labeltext = StringVar()
    self.labeltext.set("")
    Label(self.root, textvariable=self.labeltext).pack()
    self.entrytext = StringVar()
    Entry(self.root, textvariable=self.entrytext).pack()
    self.entrytext.trace('w', self.entry_changed)

    self.root.mainloop()



def entry_changed(self, a, b, c):
    s = self.entrytext.get()
    try:
        a=int(s)*4.3
        self.labeltext.set(a)
    except:
        if s=="":
           self.labeltext.set("")
    else:
        self.labeltext.set("invalid")


MyApp()
```

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:** As @BillTheLizard pointed out, much more likely that you forgot to indent your `else` statement properly. Therefore disregard basically everything below and add four spaces in front of `else:` and `self.labeltext.set("invalid")` :)

Your issue is with the usage of `try/except`. When you use `else` as part of a `try/except` block, the `else` piece will execute if the `try` clause does not raise an exception. Therefore in your case, anytime the `try` block completes successfully and executes `self.labeltext.set(a)`, it goes to the `else` clause and overwrites the same text.

In order to accomplish what I think you're trying to accomplish, try something like this:

```
def entry_changed(self, a, b, c):
    s = self.entrytext.get()

    try:
        a = int(s)
        if a > 0:
            a *= 4.3 # -> a = a * 4.3
            self.labeltext.set(a)
    except ValueError: # Always specify what kind of exception you are catching
        if s == "":
            self.labeltext.set("")
        else:
            self.labeltext.set("invalid")
```

I removed the `else` because it sounded like you wanted anything that wasn't a number or was < 0 to return `invalid`. Your previous `except` handled an empty string differently, so this can be adjusted if need be.

Comment: That looks like an indentation problem (not the only one).  I think the `else:` is supposed to be at the same indentation level as `if s=="":`.

Comment: @BilltheLizard Ha, well now I feel silly :) Good call.

Comment: Well I can't even get the code to run at all, so I wasn't sure.  :)

Comment: @BilltheLizard  Haha, well that makes me feel better then. I (think) I have it running now, and surprise surprise, you look to have been right :)